# Why is my imported image asset completely black in color?

Tags: android

I am trying to import a png image to use in my app, from *File* -> *New* -> *Image Asset*. After choosing my desired image file, my preview is this:

[image: This is the preview I get]

I have tried importing multiple .png files. All of them when imported show black in color. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you set custom color to #000000. Don't apply any theme from dropdown option and you can see the actual color.

Comment: There's only *HOLO_DARK*, *HOLO_LIGHT* and *CUSTOM* in Theme. No matter whatever I click, it doesn't show the actual image